# Как изменить формат дат полученных с сервера?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

С сервера прилетает массив объектов с датами. Запрос делается с помощью axios в проекте vue js.

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"created": "2020-04-15T05:15:26.312Z",
]
},
{
"id": "2",
"created": "2020-04-15T05:20:25.199Z",
},
{
"id": "3",
"created": "2020-04-15T05:23:48.444Z",
},
{
"id": "4",
"created": "2020-04-15T06:35:08.060Z",
},
{
"id": "5",
"created": "2020-04-15T08:01:01.349Z",
}
]
```

Как изменить формат даты на удобочитаемый на ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ:СС по местному времени или по Москве. Я его выгружаю списком в окне. Типо так.

- 2020-04-15T05:15:26.312Z
- 2020-04-15T05:20:25.199Z
- 2020-04-15T05:23:48.444Z
- 2020-04-15T06:35:08.060Z

А должно быть так

- 15.04.2020, 15:26.31
- и так далее

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/date

Comment: Да читал документацию, но проблема в том что не могу сообразить как массив данных обработать. Данная new Date('2020-04-15T05:15:26.312Z').toLocaleString() подходит для решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    sortData:function () {
      const array =  [];
      const keys = Object.keys(this.item);
      const values = Object.values(this.item);
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
        if (values[i]) {
            array.push(new Date(values[i].created).toLocaleString());
            Object.assign(this.arrayServer[i], {dataFormat:arrayData[i]});
        }
      }
      return array;
    },
```